# How to show $2$ vectors don't span $\mathbb{R}^3$ algebraically.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ don't span $\mathbb{R}^3$ algebraically, i.e. with system of equations. $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}+ c_2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\iff \begin{cases} x_1=-c_1+c_2 \\ x_2=2c_1 +c_2 \\ x_3=-c_1 +2c_2\end{cases}$.

Then multiplying the 3rd equation with $-1$ and adding to eq.1 we get $-x_1+x_3=c_2$ and then from equation 2 we get $c_1=(x_2-c_2)/2=(x_2+x_1-x_3)/2$. I'm thinking since it is impossible for 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to span the whole space we should've gotten a contradiction somewhere. From how it looks now, since $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$ was arbitrary chosen it seems the two vectors span the whole space.

Comment: Definitely, these two vectors can't span full space $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension $3$. In your proof, you can check the third equation is not satisfied by the solution of the first two.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check if those values $c_1$ and $c_2$ you got actually work in all 3 of your original 3 equations. (They don't.)

Comment: So I need to check it for all the three equations that it works?

Comment: They don't unless $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$ satisfy a certain linear relation.

Comment: Yes, you have to check. You started with those equations and made certain deductions, but that logical implication only goes in one direction. Your calculation shows that those values $c_1, c_2$ are the only values that *could* possibly work, but you haven't checked that they actually *do* work. And, as it turns out, they don't work (in general), so there is no solution.

Comment: Ok, so if I get this right. I just need to put $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the LHS of the equivalence arrow and if it doesn't give me equality then I'm done.

Comment: LHS or RHS... they are equivalent, so it doesn't matter which one you check.

Comment: To be clear, the LHS and RHS of the equivalence you wrote in your question goes in both directions. But there is another arrow that you haven't shown, going from the RHS to the calculation deriving your supposed values for $c_1$ and $c_2$. That arrow only goes in one direction.

Comment: Thanks! That made it a lot clearer.